# Regular expression in python : findall

Tags: python, regex

```py
re.findall(r'[\w]+@+[\w.]','blahh ggg@google.com yipee']
```

returns `['ggg@g']`

Why doesn't it returns `['ggg@google.com']` or at least `['ggg@google']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\w+@+[\w.]+

         ^^
```

You have failed to add a quantifier.So it will get only one character after `@`.

It should be

```
`re.findall(r'[\w]+@+[\w.]+','blahh ggg@google.com yipee')`
```

Also if there can be only one `@` you can remove the quantifier ahead of it to make it `\w+@[\w.]+`

Output:`['ggg@google.com']`

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/21)

`Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]`

`Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]`

Answer (score 0):

Here in `[\w]+@+[\w.]`, you are just checking for single character after `@`.
That's why it just compare `g` after `@` and stops.
You must check the multiple occurrences of word after `@` by using `*` or `+`.

```
*= Zero or more occurrences Ex. ggg@google,com, ggg@
+=One or more occurrences Ex ggg@g, ggg@googlw.com
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall(r'[\w]+@+[\w.]','blahh ggg@google.com yipee')`, lets break it down:

At first `[\w]` will match any alphanumeric character so, it will match all the characters except spaces and "@".

Then `[\w]+` will match one or more of the successive alphanumeric character so that leaves us with `blahh`, `ggg`, `google`, `com` and `yipee`.

Now `[\w]+@` will match a "@" after the previously matches, but only`ggg` has a "@" character immediately after it so only `ggg@` is matched.

Again, `[\w]+@+` will match "@" one or more time, as we have only one "@" after `ggg` so the previous match remains the same i.e. `ggg@`.

Next we have `[\w]+@+[\w.]` means that there can be a single alphanumeric character or a literal `.` after the match, `ggg@` has `g` after it so its get selected making the match `ggg@g`.

So, finally we get [`ggg@g`] as the result.

To print `['ggg@google.com']` try this:

```
re.findall(r'\w+@\w+\.\w+','blahh ggg@google.com yipee')
```